# Column based intersect on two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to do something similar to a column based intersect on two tables.
The tables are:

- `LogTag`: a log can have zero or more tags
- `MatchingRule`: a matching rule consists of one or more tags that define the rule

A log can have zero or more rules matched to it. I will be passing in a `MatchingRuleID` and expecting to return all logs that match that rule.

**Expected Result:** A result set of matching `LogID`s. Eg. passing in `MatchingRuleID = 30` should return `LogID` 101. `MatchingRuleID = 31` should return `LogID` 101 & 100.

Also, the `LogTag` table could have millions of rows so an efficient query is preferred.

**The question:** How to find all `LogID`s that match with a specified rule definition?

[image]

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tag
(
    TagID INT,
    TagName NVARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Tag (TagID, TagName)
VALUES (1, 'tag1'), (2, 'tag2'), (3, 'tag3')

CREATE TABLE dbo.LogTag
(
    LogID INT,
    TagID INT
)
INSERT INTO dbo.LogTag (LogID, TagID)
VALUES (100, 1), (101, 1), (101, 2), (101, 3), (101, 4), (102, 2), (102, 3)  

CREATE TABLE dbo.MatchingRule
(
    MatchingRuleID INT,
    TagID INT
)
INSERT INTO dbo.MatchingRule (MatchingRuleID, TagID)
VALUES (30, 1), (30, 2), (30, 3), (31, 1)
```

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: @Squirrel, edit made to clarify

Comment: where is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important to have the proper clustered index on the tables. I've put an alternative index in comments for `#log_tag` which might improve performance for large sets. Since I do not have the proper sample to test on, you will have to verify which is best.

```
CREATE TABLE #tag(tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY,tag_name NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #tag (tag_id,tag_name)VALUES
    (1,'tag1'),(2,'tag2'),(3,'tag3');

-- Try this key for large sets: PRIMARY KEY(tag_id,log_id));
CREATE TABLE #log_tag(log_id INT,tag_id INT,PRIMARY KEY(log_id,tag_id))
INSERT INTO #log_tag (log_id,tag_id)VALUES
    (100,1),(101,1),(101,2),(101,3),(101,4),(102,2),(102,3);

CREATE TABLE #matching_rule(matching_rule_id INT,tag_id INT,PRIMARY KEY(matching_rule_id,tag_id));
INSERT INTO #matching_rule(matching_rule_id,tag_id)VALUES
    (30,1),(30,2),(30,3),(31,1);

DECLARE @matching_rule_id INT=31;

;WITH required_tags AS (
    SELECT tag_id
    FROM #matching_rule
    WHERE matching_rule_id=@matching_rule_id
)
SELECT lt.log_id
FROM required_tags AS rt 
     INNER JOIN #log_tag AS lt ON
         lt.tag_id=rt.tag_id
GROUP BY lt.log_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM required_tags);

DROP TABLE #log_tag;
DROP TABLE #matching_rule;
DROP TABLE #tag;
```

The results are the ones in your **Expected Result** for both 30 & 31.

Execution plan for the index used in the script:

[image: Execution plan for index used in script]

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faf49/2)

```
DECLARE @InputMatchingRuleId  INT = 30
;WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LT.TAGID) AS RN,LT.TagID,LT.LOGID 
    FROM MatchingRule MR INNER JOIN LogTag LT ON LT.TagID = MR.TagID 
    WHERE MatchingRuleID=@InputMatchingRuleId

),
CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS RN2,LOGID FROM CTE1 C1 WHERE C1.RN=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN2+1 as RN2,C2.LOGID 
    FROM CTE1 C1 INNER JOIN CTE2 C2 ON C1.RN = C2.RN2+1 AND C1.LOGID = C2.LOGID
)

  SELECT DISTINCT LOGID FROM CTE2 
  WHERE RN2>(CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(RN2) FROM CTE2)=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This will only work with SQL Server 2008+**

Here's the query I came up with:

```
DECLARE @RuleID INT
SELECT @RuleID = 30

SELECT LogID
FROM LogTag lt
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TagID, MatchingRuleID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY MatchingRuleID) TagCount
        FROM MatchingRule
    ) mr 
    ON lt.TagID = mr.TagID
        AND mr.MatchingRuleID = @RuleID
GROUP BY LogID, TagCount
HAVING COUNT(*) = TagCount
```

So basically I match all `TagID`'s within the specified matching rule and then once I know that all tags match I check to see if the count of tags from the `MatchingRule` table matches the (now filtered and grouped) count of tags from the `LogTag` table.

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
; with rules as
(
    select  TagID, cnt = sum(count(*)) over()
    from    dbo.MatchingRule
    where   MatchingRuleID  = @MatchingRuleID
    group by TagID
)
select  LogID
from    rules r
    inner join LogTag lt    on  r.TagID = lt.TagID
group by LogID, cnt
having  count(*) = r.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.LogID
from dbo.MatchingRule r
inner join dbo.LogTag l on l.TagID = r.TagID
where r.MatchingRuleID = 31
```

another approach is to identify all tags and then:

```
select l.LogID
from dbo.LogTag l
where exists(select 1 from @Tags t where t.TagID = l.TagID)
```